# How to make pure Node.js websocket client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

Assuming that web sockets based on TCP I have created a simple TCP client, but I cannot get any response from *echo.websocket.org*. What am I doing wrong?

```js
const connectionData: any = {
  protocol: 'ws:',
  host: 'echo.websocket.org',
  port: '80'
}
var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(connectionData, function () {
  console.log('Connected');
  client.write('Reply this.');
});

client.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('Received: ' + data);
});

client.on('close', function () {
  console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

Comment: Web sockets are a separate protocol on top of TCP.  You need to use a library or reimplement that protocol yourself.

Comment: @SLaks, So the implementation of web socket client in Node.js is not that trivial?

Comment: @IlyaShakalov no it's not trivial. In fact, it's a protocol built on top of HTTP, not just raw TCP. It would be easier to open a [`http.request()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) to implement a web socket. Here's [the RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455) that should help you implement the protocol should you choose not to use [an existing solution](https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket).